# In the course of answer editing

Tags: discussion, edits

Often times I post an answer and then later on, suddenly have an epiphany of what the question poster really wanted, or something that would suit them better for the situation that had described in their question.

When such an epiphany occurs and I have a minute to go back and edit, should I keep the old information and create a new section within the same answer or should I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> and start the entire answer all over?

Comment: "It depends." ;-) Does the "old" information still contain useful content in the context of the question? Or is it *entirely* useless, now that you've had the epiphany? Personally I'd post an entirely new answer and (possibly) delete my old one. Otherwise you'd "transfer" votes (both up and down) to the new answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your answer is a completely different method, post as a new answer. If your just correcting your answer(due to typos or what not), or tidying up the code, just edit it, then comment on it letting everyone know you optimized it a little bit more.